# In Line interface, I must call close() for all instance, or only when Line is opened?

Tags: java, javasound, try-with-resources, autocloseable

By the definition of `AutoCloseable` interface,
I must call `close()` for **ALL** instances.
i.e. I must write like this.

```
try(A a = new A()){
    //do something
}
```

In `java.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine` interface,
or more commonly, in `java.sound.sampled.Line` interface,
is it required to call `close()` for **ALL** instances,
or I must call `close()` **ONLY AFTER** `open()` has called ?

If the official document explicitly states that I must `close` only when `isOpened` ,
I want to write like this.
but I couldn't find mention.

```
//can I write like this ?  

SourceDataLine sdl;
try{
    sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(audioFormat);
    sdl.open(audioFormat,bufferSize);
}catch(LineUnavailableException ex){
    throw new RuntimeException(null,ex);
}
try(SourceDataLine sdlInTryWithResources = sdl){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: try-with-resources was invented to clean your code up a bit, not to make it even more complicated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual question should be “does it harm to call `close()` when the data line has not been opened?” and the answer is “no”, so you can simply use

```
try(SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(audioFormat)) {
    sdl.open(audioFormat, bufferSize);
    // work with sdl
}
catch(LineUnavailableException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

Note that `javax.sound.sampled.Line` has been deliberately changed in Java 7 to extend `AutoCloseable`, whose sole purpose is to allow the resource to be used within a try-with-resource statement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are overthinking things.

Just image try-with-resources would not exist and write down your code as you would have done prior Java 1.7.

For sure, you end up with something like:

```
Whatever somethingThatNeedsClosing = null;
try {
  somethingThatNeedsClosing = ...
  somethingThatNeedsClosing.whatever();
} catch (NoIdeaException e) {
  error handling
} finally {
  if (somethingThatNeedsClosing != null) {
    somethingThatNeedsClosing.close()
  }
}
```

Try-with-resources simply allows you to reduce this example accordingly.

In other words: try-with-resources allows you to define one (or more) resource(s) that will be used within the try block; and that will *finally* be closed. As in: each and any resource declared for try ... will be closed.

More specifically: don't think about *other* instances of your resource. Focus on the *one* that you are currently dealing with.